# How to delete a LaunchDaemon from Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, launchd

I attempted to create a .plist file in order to run my Python script through Mac Launchd. I entered the following into terminal:

```
sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.my.program.plist
```

I want to now delete this .plist file, and I had tried to look for this file in my Mac's Library folder. However, I could not find it.

How would I be able to find this file in order to delete it? Was it not created? And how can I check this?

Comment: as you have run that command as sudo, I think the file was created, you can delete it with "sudo rm -rf  /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.my.program.plist"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't get an alert, but I typed your code in and hopefully it deleted

Answer (score 0):

should be in your Macintosh HD > Library > LaunchDaemons